# Getting 400 BAD REQUEST when uploading a blob to JAVA server Jersey API

Tags: java, ajax, html5-canvas, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to upload a cropped image sending it as a blob and getting an 400 http error.
When checking it carefully, I've noticed the following exception:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed.*

The JavaScript code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("pic", cblob); //append the blob
$.ajax("/wsbasestructure/ws/users/test", {
  data: fd,
  type: "PUT",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function (data) {
  }
});
```

The Java code:

```
@PUT
@Path("/test")
public String updatePic(@FormDataParam("pic") InputStream file){
    System.out.println(file);
    return null;
}
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it `HTTP PUT` or `POST` in `Ajax` code snippet?

Comment: @harshavmb, PUT.

Answer (score 0):

See :

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.0.3/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataParam.html

You need your form to be a multipart/form-data content type.
So you need :

```
contentType: multipart/form-data
```

And maybe you should change the Web Service.

Try this :

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/test")
public String updatePic(
    @FormDataParam("pic") InputStream file,
    @FormDataParam("pic") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {
    ...
}
```

Source: [Jersey doc](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9498)

Comment: It seems not to be what you pointed out. Still getting the same exception. (I forgot to describe in the question that I already tried that)

Comment: Did you also try to add the annotation  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE) ?

Comment: Yes, it's defined in the class itself.
I don't think it would be something related to multipart definitions cause when I send a file like this `$("#input")[0].files[0]`. It works.
I'm having this problem when uploading a blob and I really need to upload this blob extraced from a html5 canvas.

Comment: How the variable cblob is initialized ?

Comment: I'm initializing this variable like this: `function canvasToBlob(canvas, type) {

        var byteString = atob(canvas.toDataURL().split(",")[1]),
                ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length),
                ia = new Uint8Array(ab),
                i;
        for (i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return new Blob([ab], {
            type: type
        });

    }
var cblob = canvasToBlob(canvas, "jpg");`.

Am I missing something?